# SQL query does not work in VB6, but the same query works properly in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, vb6, oracle10g

We have written the following query which returns records in Oracle but when the same query is executed through VB6.0, it returns 0 records.

```sql
Select * 
 from crdh 
where expdate between (TO_DATE('03-Dec-2002','DD-MON-YYYY')) 
  and (TO_DATE('31-Dec-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')) 
  and CS = 'AA'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please show the code that executes the query in VB6.

Comment: I'm not really sure if oracle would be happy with the `where and` part

Comment: As @SWeko said - did you try after removing and from where and

Comment: I have added 'where and' by mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `where and` in your question is just a typo and not really part of your query, the reason for your problem might be a NLS issue; the "MON" part your your format string is culture dependend. You might be able to solve that by setting the language in the environment, but IMO it's perferable to use language-independend numerical month formats instead, i.e.

```
Select * 
 from crdh 
where expdate between (TO_DATE('03-12-2002','DD-MM-YYYY')) 
  and (TO_DATE('31-12-2012','DD-MM-YYYY')) 
  and CS='AA'
```

Comment: Or better yet IMHO, use ANSI syntax and the ISO date format ... "expdate between date '2002-12-03' and 2012'12'31"

Comment: @DavidAldridge do you mean `expdate between date '2002-12-03' and date '2012-12-31'`?

Comment: @JackDouglas yes quite so ... sorry i was eating toast at the same time